# How to correctly display a tab controller in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm making a login screen for my app and everything works as intented until I try to present my main view after the login(which uses a Tab Bar Controller).

The only problem is that it displays just the first item on the tab bar. I have to press the other buttons for the to appear.

Im using this code:

```
//after login...
var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var vc: TabBarViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as! TabBarViewController

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My guess is that I need to load them all at the same time, but I dont know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it recently. I loaded my tabBarController and the login screen together, once the user has logged in (or completed the first screen experience) you can modally dismiss the controller.

```
func showloginView() {

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginViewController: LoginTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginTVC") as! LoginTableViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginTVC") as! LoginTableViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

for displaying your tabBarController and editing of any of the tabBarItems

```
let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
let tabBarRootViewControllers: Array = tabBarController!.viewControllers!
let nav = tabBarRootViewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

If you link an UIButton, you can open a UITabBarController using this (providing you're using a Storyboard)

```
@IBAction func openTabBar(sender: AnyObject) {
        var tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        self.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

That'll pop the current view and open the tab bar controller.

Comment: This is only open first tab, how do I open second tab in tab bar controller.